# Is it me or Visual Studio 2015 doesn't provide intellisense for conditional compilation symbols?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

A simple question really..
I don't know about c# but in vb.net in VS2013 I can get intellisense
about compilation constants when using #if etc.

But in VS2015 this doesn't happen..

Has it been removed or do I have a problem on my machine?

This is VS2013

[image: VS2013]

And this is VS2015

[image]

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem. Maybe you can open a [Bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015/)?

Comment: yeah if it's not only me then I will..